# How to align these two elements in this position in HTML?

Tags: html, css, layout

I have two elements which I want to align this way on Top Bar :

[image]

**Below you can see the HTML and CSS for the two of the elements:**

I tried using margins or padding but it didn't look I was going anywhere like that.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.example {
  margin: 3px auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="example">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
      <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button">+ New location</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: It's a little hard to tell what you need but maybe take the 'new location' button out of the 'float: right' div and putting the two buttons beside each other would solve it. You could easily add space between the two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `right`?

First change `float: left;` in your two CSS classes (input field and button) to `float: right;`.
This way, the input field and the button are next to each other on the right side.

Then you can move your "right-floated" elements using:
`right: 50px;`, for isntance.

Answer (score 0):

You could have use `flex` system layout to make it easier, but to do this in the way it is we should change couple of things:

1. Change order of `div.example` and the div that contains new location button in html
2. Set `float: right` to both `div.example` and the other div
3. Set `margin-right: 50px` to second div

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.example {

  /* NEW */
  float: right;
  /* Endof NEW */

  margin: 3px auto;
  max-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="topnav">
    
    <!-- Changed order -->

    <div style="float:right;margin-right:50px;">
      <button type="button">+ New location</button>
    </div>

    <div class="example">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
      <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
    <!-- Endof change -->
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed order of elements, add a little margin and float right to the first element.

```
   <div>
      <div class="topnav" style="margin-right: 100px;">
        <div style="float:right;">
          <button type="button">+ New location</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="example">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
          <button type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use flex and/or multi-column presentation, but with your current html-structure, one of the simplest options would be to add the second button to the "example" div and to use separated classes for buttons.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
  border-top-left-radius: 6px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.example button {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 40px;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
}
.example .button--search { 
  border-left: none;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
  border-top-right-radius: 6px;
  width: 50px;
}
.example .button--new-location {
   margin-left: 15px;
   border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="topnav">
    <div class="example">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
      <button type="button" class="button--search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
      <button type="button" class="button--new-location">+ New location</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```